# Regular Expression usage in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm a new bie to python and need some assistance in the usage of regular expression.

I have a string something like this:

New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)

from the above string I want to extract the following text using regular expression

20120418-abcdef-1 
0.0.0.1

I can do this by split but I feel it is an ineffective way of doing this. I tried using regular expression but could not narrow down.

for example, I used

```
sdk_version = re.search(r"SDK(.*)", lines,)
                    print sdk_version.group(1)
```

but this gave the version 0.0.0.1) along with the paranthesis I did not know how to elimate ')' .. Need some help here..

Thanks
-Vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming version numbers can only contain letters, digits, dots and dashes, this is all you need:

```
version, sdk = re.findall(r'(?:Version: |SDK )([\w.-]+)', s)
```

Example:

```
s = "New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)"

import re
version, sdk = re.findall(r'(?:Version: |SDK )([\w.-]+)', s)

print version
print sdk

## 20120418-abcdef-1
## 0.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)"
>>> import re
>>> version = re.compile(r"(?<=Version: )\d*-[a-z]*-\d")
>>> version.search(s).group()
'20120418-abcdef-1'
```

This matches

```
(preceded by "Version: ")
a string of digits
hyphen
a string of lowercase letters
hyphen
a digit
```

---

Similarly,

```
>>> subversion = re.compile(r"(?<=SDK )\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*")
>>> subversion.search(s).group()
'0.0.0.1'
```

matches

```
(preceded by "SDK ")
a string of digits
a dot
a string of digits
a dot
a string of digits
a dot
a string of digits
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I don't know if all your strings will look exactly like the one provided, but the regular expression for the exact string you provided would be:

```
: (.*) \(based on SDK (.*)\)
```

This does the following:

**:** - Start matching after a : appears.

**(** - This will open a group (this is a special construct for regular expressions that will allow you to refer to the captured value later).

**.*** - This part simply matches everything until a space.

**\(** - This will match a 'real' brace and NOT open a subgroup.

**\)** - This will match a 'real' closing brace and NOT close a subgroup.

So in `python` this would look like this:

```
import re
s = "New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)"
r = re.compile(r": (.*) \(based on SDK (.*)\)")
m = r.search(s)
m.groups()
>> ('20120418-abcdef-1', '0.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may want to do

```
>>> st="New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)"
>>> "".join(re.findall(":[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*\(.*SDK(.*)\)",st)[0])
'20120418-abcdef-1 0.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the SDK version specifically, .* is too broad for what you want here -- it matches everything, so it will match the whole rest of the string. You might use the regular expression body "SDK ([0-9.]+)" and then take the first group. (The "[0-9.]+" will match a string of numeric characters and periods.)

For the version string, you could match against something like "Version: ([a-bA-B0-9-]+) (" and take the first group -- this says you're looking for a string composed of alphanumeric characters and hyphens, and followed by a space and an open-paren.

Answer (score 1):

@Gjallar already wrote a very good answer.  Here is a slight tweak to his answer:

```
import re
s = "New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1)"
r = re.compile(r":\s+(.*)\s+\(based on SDK\s+(\S+)\s*\)")
m = r.search(s)
m.groups()
>> ('20120418-abcdef-1', '0.0.0.1')
```

Several places where he had a space, I replaced it with `\s+` which matches one or more of any kind of white space.  So if an extra space gets in there, or a tab, or whatever, this would still match.

Likewise, I changed the pattern for the SDK string.  First, I changed it from `.*` to `\S+`, so instead of matching anything at all it now only matches non-whitespace characters and there must be at least one.  I also added `\s*` which matches zero or more of any kind of white space.  This will do nothing if there is no white space, but if there is some it will match it; but it's outside of the parentheses so it won't capture the white space.  So, the SDK string will match but will not include any white space:

```
s = "New builds available Version: 20120418-abcdef-1 (based on SDK 0.0.0.1 )"
```

With @Gjallar's original pattern, the SDK string would be `"0.0.0.1 "` but with my pattern you still get `"0.0.0.1"`.